# Proof by contradiction question, falsum symbol used

Tags: proof-writing

I have a question on proof by contradiction.  The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) page steps are to assume $\lnot P$ and derive a contradiction, formulated $\lnot p \implies \bot$.  The law of non-contradiction is $\lnot(q \land \lnot q)$.  Wiki explains $\bot$ is the logical contradiction or a false statement.  It's my understanding the logical contradiction is ($p \land \lnot p$).

I have some confusion about the term *contradiction* and the $\bot$ symbol.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) writes a *contradiction* is logical incompatibility or incongruity between **two** or more propositions.  Then Wiki states that In modern formal logic, the term is mainly used instead for a single proposition, often denoted by the falsum symbol.
$\bot$.  Wiki also has an article to assume $\lnot P$ and derive $\lnot Q \land Q$.

When following the steps, should one derive a contradiction or simply a false statement?

Did perhaps the Wiki authors really intend $\lnot p \implies (q \land \lnot q)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. It seems that what you're saying is that a contradiction is the falsum symbol and then talking about proving p implies q by contradiction?

Comment: I'm asking about the steps to proof by contradiction and the discrepancies in the Wiki articles.  I do not mention $p \implies q$, where did you see that?

Comment: Except your first wiki article isn't the main proof by contradiction page  it's just on contradiction

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it. The point of proof by contradiction is to assume $\neg p$ and show that it implies $p$, which is a contradiction, because if $\neg p \implies p$ were true, that would further imply that $\neg p \wedge p$ is true, which definitively ⊥ (false).